# Detect ActionResult type in ActionFilter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a global `ActionFilter` executing on each `ActionResult`. Is it possible to detect the ActionResult type (such as a `JsonResult` vs. an `ActionResult`) inside the `ActionFilter`?

For instance, I want the `ActionFilter` to immediately exit here:

```
public JsonResult someAjaxAction()
{
}
```

But I'd like it to do it's magic here:

```
public ActionResult PageView()
{
}
```

Yes, I know I could just use an `ActionFilter` attribute and decorate the actions I'd like to execute this on, but I'd like to keep it as a global `ActionFilter` and detect inside the action whether I need to perform the desired work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
        {
            ...
        }
        else if (filterContext.Result is JsonResult)
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to change my override to OnResultExecuted, because OnActionExecuting has filterContext.Result == null (since the action has not been executed yet). Thx!

Answer (score 0):

[ActionExecutingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext.aspx) have property named [result](http://ActionExecutingContext.Result) which is ActionResult type might solve your problem.